If $A\subset \mathbb N$ has positive lower density then there exists $r$ such that $A\cup A+1\cup\ldots A+r$ have lower density one
I think the questions below are true; however, I have not been able to prove it.
Suppose that $A\subset \mathbb N$ have positive lower-density i.e.
$$d_*(A):=\liminf_{n\to\infty} \frac{A\cap \{1,2,\ldots,n\}}{n} \geq \theta>0.$$

Question I: Is it true that there exists $r\in\mathbb N$ such that the $$A_r :=
 \{a+i; a\in A\ \text{and }i\in\{0,1,\ldots, r\}\} $$
such that $d_*(A_r)=1$?


Question II: Is it true that for every $\varepsilon >0$ there exists $r=r(\varepsilon)\in\mathbb N$, such that $d_*(A_r) \geq 1-\varepsilon.$

Does anyone know whether Question I or II is true? I would appreciate a proof or any references that address any of these two questions.

I doubt that this is true. Try something like $$A=\bigcup_{k\in 2\mathbb{N}}(\mathbb{N} \cap [2^k, 2^{k+1}-1]).$$ Thickening the set by $r$ only gives you a logarithmic correction which does not change the lower density at all.

I don't have the time to actual check. But you can certainly tweak it to make it work. You only need to have polynomially long blocks.

See properties and example here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density to see that the lower density of my example truly is positive.

I agree with you; thank you for your comment! If you want to post your comment as an answer, I would be happy to accept it.

You are very welcome. This example has destroyed a lot of my conjectures in the past. It is helpful for sanity check.

Neither of the two questions holds true. Pick
$$A=\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} ([2^{2k}, 2^{2k+1}-1]\cap \mathbb{N}).$$
One can compute that
$$d_*(A)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1+2^2+\dots +2^{2n}}{2^{2n+1}-1}=\frac{1}{3}>0.$$
However, we get that
$$\frac{\vert (A_r\setminus A)\cap [1,n]\vert}{n}\leq \frac{2r \log_4(n)}{n}.$$
The intuition is that $A\cap [1, n]$ consists of at most $\log_4(n)$ blocks and when we thicken by $r$ we add at most $2r$ elements per block ($r$ on either side).
Hence, $d_*(A_r)=d_*(A)$ for all $r\in \mathbb{N}$.
